# Missing components to configure and manage IIS express

Tags: asp.net-core, visual-studio-2019, iis-express

I am attempting to launch & debug an ASP.NET 5 project from within Visual Studio, and getting the error message "Missing components to configure and manage IIS express".

[image]

The solution builds without error. But IIS Express will not start and allow me to debug.

I have tried restarting Visual Studio and ensuring that the ports used by the project are free to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the error message, we can have a try with the following:

1.Close solution, delete .vs folder if this issue only happens in the specific solution

2.Delete the folder IIS express folder: C:\Users\UserName\Documents\iisexpress

3.Delete temporary ASP.NET Files located: C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root

Answer (score 2):

close Visual Studio
try deleting .vs folder and rerunning
open Visual Studio and try relaunching

Answer (score 1):

Start > Run > `appwiz.cpl` > Add/Remove Components > Install the full version of IIS.

Or if the full version of Internet Information Services (IIS) is currently installed do a Repair.

Comment: Install the full version was the solution for me. Thanks